# Select lowest nested selector when clicked

Tags: jquery, click, nested

I would like to click `$('.sub-menu')` selector and return the lowerst nested item that was clicked, rather than the highest. e.g., when I click "enlish", "root" is returned becasue "english" is a child of "root". I want "english" returned when I select "english".

```
<div ID="browse_container">
    <div class="sub-menu">Root
        <div class="sub-menu">English</div>
        <div class="sub-menu">Maths
            <div class="sub-menu">Year 1</div>
            <div class="sub-menu">Year 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-menu">▷ Science</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my script is simply:

```
$('.sub-menu, #root').on('click', function(event){
    alert($(this).text())
});
```

Comment: as a personal suggestion, this type of list semantically should be put together using unordered lists (`<UL>`) and list items (`<LI>`) rather than nested divs. but again, this is just a personal suggestion. Don't think there is anything wrong with what your markup looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.sub-menu, #root').on('click', function(event){
    alert($(event.target).text());
    return false; // I stop the bubble
});
```

you want the `event.target` [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.target)

see example here http://jsfiddle.net/qeVXa/

Comment: or another one for fyi `.stopPropagation` api `:)`

Comment: with jQuery return false also fires `event.stopPropagation()` as well as `event.cancelDefault()`

Answer (score 2):

ah, answer is to use `$(event.target).text()`

instead of `$(this).text()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo** http://jsfiddle.net/H5Eq7/

API - `.stopPropagation` http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

**stopPropagation**

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

This should fit the cause `:)`

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sub-menu, #root').on('click', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert($(this).text())
    });

});​
```